# File delete history in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a way I can view a list of files that the user has recently deleted, assuming they have already been removed from the recycle bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such list which is easily accessible within Windows, but you can use a program such as [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to scan for deleted files, and sort them by date to see the latest ones removed.